# Why is my keyboard being loaded whenever I load my UIImagePickerController view?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a `UIActionSheet` for selecting between the camera or the photo library to embed an image into a `UITextView` but for whatever reason it's loading the keyboard. I force close the keyboard on press of the left button of the bar surrounding the `UITextView` but when I press photo library I opens and closes the keyboard before pushing to the image picker VC.

```
override func didPressLeftButton(sender: AnyObject?) {
    let cameraMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

    let photoLibrary = UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .Default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
        self.openPhotoLibrary()
    })

    let takePhoto = UIAlertAction(title: "Open Camera", style: .Default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
        self.textView.endEditing(true)
        self.openCamera()
    })

    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

    cameraMenu.addAction(photoLibrary)
    cameraMenu.addAction(takePhoto)
    cameraMenu.addAction(cancel)

    self.presentViewController(cameraMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func openPhotoLibrary() {
    imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func openCamera(){
    imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
    imagePicker.showsCameraControls = true
    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        // Image resizing
        let textViewWidth: CGFloat = self.textView.frame.size.width - 20
        let percentResize = textViewWidth / pickedImage.size.width
        let toBeExportedHeight = pickedImage.size.height * percentResize
        let resizedImage = ImageManipulationManager.sharedInstance.resizeImage(exportedWidth: Int(textViewWidth),exportedHeight: Int(toBeExportedHeight), originalImage: pickedImage)

        // Storage into TextView
        let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
        attachment.image = resizedImage
        let attString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
        textView.textStorage.insertAttributedString(attString, atIndex: textView.selectedRange.location)
        pastedImageLocations.append(textView.selectedRange.location)
        textView.selectedRange.location = textView.selectedRange.location + 1
        textView.textStorage.insertAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "\n"), atIndex: textView.selectedRange.location)
        textView.selectedRange.location = textView.selectedRange.location + 1
        textView.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16.0)

        // Image Caching
        if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage, 0.50) {
            socketMessages.append(["data": data])
            haneke.set(value: data, key: String(unsafeAddressOf(attachment.image!)))
            print("Image cached as \"\(String(unsafeAddressOf(attachment.image!)))\"")
        }
    }
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    self.textView.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: self.textView.becomeFirstResponder() will open keyboard

Comment: I don't want the keyboard to appear, I want it to stop appearing when I present the `UIImagePickerController`

Comment: keyboard appears when you finish picking image from image picker not on present , you can remove `self.textView.becomeFirstResponder()` and then             `[self.view endEditing:YES];`

Comment: It's appearing before I load the view controller not after.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

I had to change

```
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
self.textView.becomeFirstResponder()
```

to

```
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) {
        self.textView.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do some changes by adding this  -

```
override func didPressLeftButton(sender: AnyObject?) {
    let cameraMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

    let photoLibrary = UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .Default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
        self.view.endEditing(true)    //**------ Add this
        self.openPhotoLibrary()
    })

    let takePhoto = UIAlertAction(title: "Open Camera", style: .Default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
        self.view.endEditing(true) //**------ Add this
        self.openCamera()
    })

    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

    cameraMenu.addAction(photoLibrary)
    cameraMenu.addAction(takePhoto)
    cameraMenu.addAction(cancel)

    self.presentViewController(cameraMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: That wasn't the problem as I call `endEditing()` in `openCamera()`. The problem is as seen below

Comment: where you are facing problem let me know, end of the image picking you again "self.textView.becomeFirstResponder()" calling keyboard so i am not getting your point what you want.